# How to add ofxKinect to visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, kinect, openframeworks, ofxkinect

How do I add ofxKinect to Visual Studio 2017? I already installed openframeworks using the extension manager.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction will help you. You can use a project generator to set addons to your project.
http://www.ofxaddons.com/pages/howto